Region of Interest option (--roi) ignored when using rpicam-still and rpicam-vid
I am attempting to use the
--roi 0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5

option with rpicam-still and rpicam-vid to achieve a digital zoom effect. I've tried the above which should keep the middle 50% of pixels both horizontally and vertically but the resulting image is the exact same whether or not the roi option was in the command line. I'm not sure what to look at next in order to figure out what the issue is.
Setup is Pi 4B and OV5647 module


--roi 0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5
I've tried the above which should keep the middle 50% of pixels both horizontally and vertically

The problem is the spaces between the values; evidently no error is thrown for invalid values, even if other parameters follow this and are properly recognized.  Eg., --roi "hello world" is just ignored as well.
Try:
--roi 0.25,0.25,0.5,0.5

And you should get what you're looking for.

Would never have guessed that it came down to the formatting of the arguments. The roi option definitely works. Thanks again goldilocks!
